# Why has my separator stopped working in read.table

Tags: r, parsing

I have a text file(myFile.txt) which I am attempting to turn into a data.frame

Here is an extract

```
 <li>

                    <a title="Data table: Grand Falls-Windsor (Census Agglomeration), Newfoundland and Labrador" href="../../details/page.cfm?Lang=E&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=010&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=Grand%20Falls-Windsor&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;GeoLevel=PR&amp;GeoCode=010&amp;TABID=1">Grand Falls-Windsor&nbsp;(<acronym title="Census Agglomeration">CA</acronym>)</a> [<a href="../../details/page_Map_Carte_Detail.cfm?Lang=E&amp;G=1&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=010&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;Custom=&amp;TABID=1&amp;geocode=010" title="Map: Grand Falls-Windsor (Census Agglomeration), Newfoundland and Labrador">map</a>]

         </li>

<li>

                    <a title="Data table: St. John's (Census Metropolitan Area), Newfoundland and Labrador" href="../../details/page.cfm?Lang=E&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=001&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=St.%20John's&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;GeoLevel=PR&amp;GeoCode=001&amp;TABID=1">St. John's&nbsp;(<acronym title="Census Metropolitan Area">CMA</acronym>)</a> [<a href="../../details/page_Map_Carte_Detail.cfm?Lang=E&amp;G=1&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=001&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;Custom=&amp;TABID=1&amp;geocode=001" title="Map: St. John's (Census Metropolitan Area), Newfoundland and Labrador">map</a>]

         </li>


df <- read.table("myFile.txt",sep="\n")
```

this works up to the end of the Grand Falls extract but then the `\n` does not seem to take effect. Here is a row of console readout as you can see there are `\n`s at end which are not taking effect.

```
\t\t\t\t\t\t<a title=Data table: St. John's (Census Metropolitan Area), Newfoundland and Labrador href=../../details/page.cfm?Lang=E&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=001&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=St.%20John's&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;GeoLevel=PR&amp;GeoCode=001&amp;TABID=1>St. Johns&nbsp;(<acronym title="Census Metropolitan Area">CMA</acronym>)</a> [<a href="../../details/page_Map_Carte_Detail.cfm?Lang=E&amp;G=1&amp;Geo1=CMA&amp;Code1=001&amp;Geo2=PR&amp;Code2=01&amp;Data=Count&amp;SearchText=&amp;SearchType=Begins&amp;SearchPR=01&amp;B1=All&amp;Custom=&amp;TABID=1&amp;geocode=001" title="Map: St. Johns (Census Metropolitan Area), Newfoundland and Labrador>map</a>]\n\t\t\t\t\t\n             </li>\n\t\t\t \n
```

Apologies for this presentation but I am having lots of trouble with Rstudio crashing when trying to copy from console

Can someone help out here. perhaps the `read.table()` is not correct approach anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these:

```
read.table("test.txt", sep="\n", quote="")
readLines(con=file("test.txt"))
```

You have a mismatched single-quote problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have an unclosed open-quote `"`

Perhaps it is only in what you copied and pasted here or is it in the data itself?

Comment: Yes it is actually a single-quote in the city name. Going through all the data I can see there is also a problem with a '-' in names. I can manage this data but is there a way of escaping these characters